# how can i export data to excel sheet using javascript

Tags: javascript, grails, groovy

Can i export a data  from a table to an excel sheet, using javascript?

I have tried some examples but without any effect i try (http://www.databison.com/index.php/html-to-excel-using-javascript-and-excel-to-html-using-vba/) and so on.

Is there any other solution?

I need to use this export in a grails application, i know that there is a plugin in grails that help me but i don't like to use it.

If there is a way in groovy or in grails other than the plugin please specify it here.

if there is any method please write the full code here.

thx a lot

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921037/jquery-table-to-csv-export

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php), its a jQuery plugin to export table data to CSV. Ill add more if I find any

Comment: it is used wiht php that i can't use it. if u find any please mention it thx

Comment: @mbayloon - Did you actually visit the link he provided? It's for a jquery plugin that does what you're asking for. Just because the site's got a `.php` doesn't mean the code on it is PHP.

Comment: hi Rob Hruska, i visit this link and i see how it work, and i conclude that it is a php code. if u see that it is not php code please mention the full code here to try it. thx

Comment: boy.. sometimes I hate SO