# How can i generate a file and offer it for download in plain javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, download, blob, fileapi

I would like to generate a text file in the javascript dynamicly, then offer this for download. Currently I can get this working to a degree with either of the following solutions:

```
content = "abc123";
document.location = "data:text/octet-stream," + encodeURIComponent(content);
```

OR

```
content = "abc123";    
var bb = new BlobBuilder();
bb.append(content);
var blob = bb.getBlob();
blob = blob.slice(0, blob.size, 'text/octet-stream');
var fr = new FileReader(); 
fr.onload = function() {document.location = this.result;}
fr.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

However, Both of these solutions, when the download box appears, will only offer a default filename of 'download' in the save as dialogue.

My question is basically, how can I change this to a specific filename for example 'readme.txt' or 'scene.obj'

Also note the data type was previously 'text/plain' however if this is used, the document switches to the new text document instead of offering it for download (as text/octet-stream seems to do).

I do not want a flash solution, javascript/html5 only suggestions please.

Cheers, Josh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to specify a suggested filename when using data: URI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri)

Comment: This does appear to be a duplicate of the suggested link, not sure why I didn't find it when I searched. People wanting an answer to this question should follow the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that, you will have to use [FileSaver](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-writer.html#idl-def-FileSaver) from FileAPI: Writer specification.
For now, it's only a draft, and according to [mailing list answer](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-html5/msg/57e722febe140a17) it isn't yet implemented in browsers.

You can watch for example on a [chromium issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=65615) to get up-to-date information about the implementation progress

UPD 02.08.2013: I have since found a [project](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) that provides FileSaver interface using neat tricks

Comment: IE10 features msSaveOrOpenBlob and msSaveBlob. Theese are two methods available in IE10 which let sites ask the user to save a blob to their computer. More at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/01/27/creating-files-through-blobbuilder.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check: [jQuery Table to CSV export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921037/jquery-table-to-csv-export)

Comment: These solutions look like they are dependent on server-side scripting, I am looking to stick to client-side. Thanks for suggestion anyway.