# Javascript Table to Excel

Tags: javascript, xml, excel, javascript-framework

I have created a javascript/HTML table. How to download this and store in excel? Any code will be of help.

This is my code for creating the table:

```
function populateTable(results) {
                var tableDiv = document.getElementById('aDiv');
                var config = { columns:
                                                [{key: 'FormattedID', width: 100},
                                                 {key: 'Name'},
                                                 {key: 'Type'},
                                                 {key: 'Method'},
                                                 {key: 'Risk'},
                                                 {key: 'Priority'}] };
                var table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(config);
                table.addRows(results.testcases);
                table.display(tableDiv);
                alert (results.testcases.length);

           }
           queryConfig = {
                type : 'testcase',
                key  : 'testcases',
                fetch: 'true'
            };
```

Thanks

Comment: You probably store your table in results.testcases object. Are you getting it from a server?

Comment: Are you looking for an Excel writer written in client-side JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [TabletoCSV jquery plugin](http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php) and to the threads that were discussed about it on StackOverflow: [jQuery Table to CSV export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921037/jquery-table-to-csv-export) and [Export to csv in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639372/export-to-csv-in-jquery)