# jQuery Datatables export to Excel in correct format

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, csv, datatables

How can we export the contents of the jQuery Datatables to proper Excel format? The current implementation only exports to .csv file. Does any one have a demo or working example for this?

More details are the discussion [here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11561/export-to-excel-willing-to-help/p1) and [here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/11561/export-to-excel-willing-to-help/p1?post#Form_Body).

Comment: use an excel library on server

Comment: Use the [Table to CSV](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/tableToCSV) plugin for jQuery. Detail: [Stackoverflow: jQuery Table to CSV export](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921037/jquery-table-to-csv-export)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to export in excel only format you have to modified the "TableTools.min.js" file.
You have to open "TableTools.min.js" file and replace "*.csv" with "*.xls" word. Then it will work export proper Excel format.

Also if you want download updated "TableTools.min.js" download by below link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8IHTmhRUyLpcjhnWWpOR3k3dlE/edit?usp=sharing

**Thanks & Regards**

Deepak Joshi

9899835174