# How do I convert an HTML table to a CSV file using ASP Classic or JQUERY

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I'm trying to figure out how to convert the following table to a CSV (Comma Seperated Value)

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I understand that you need to use something like

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=myfilename.csv");
```

But what else do you need to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3395921/472134

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Table to CSV export](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921037/jquery-table-to-csv-export)

Comment: Thanks, the example that you showed me is a solution for PHP

Comment: The First link takes you to an answer for Asp.net

Comment: @ClydeLobo which still doesn't help someone using asp-classic; though the jQuery code in the accepted answer could be of use - we'd need to know more about the use case.

Answer (score 2):

The header you're after is Content-Type:

```
  Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv");
```